# Double thumbnails?

Tags: images, post-thumbnails

is it possible to use the thumbnail mechanic twice? I find the thumbnail API really useful for allowing users to place in there own graphics, so that I can control size and position easily. All they have to do is remember to click featured image. I would like two such mechanisms on my page, any idea how I could do this?

Preferably hand coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout the [multiple post thumbnails plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/multiple-post-thumbnails/).  It will allow you to define multiple post thumbnails for specific post types.

Comment: I would like to code it myself, ideally. I shall do my best to pick this apart and take out the bits I like.

Comment: It's opensource.  You can do whatever you like to it.

Comment: I know its an old question but this may help others. Try this plugin - http://wordpress.org/plugins/dynamic-featured-image. It will allow you to add multiple featured image using a graphical interface. It will save lot of your development time.