# Multiple Post thumbnails (at least three)

Tags: post-thumbnails, customization

How do I attain multiple post thumbnails, and have more that three thumbnails for each post.

Comment: See: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2114/double-thumbnails

Comment: Why community wiki?

Comment: No longer community wiki.

Comment: Old question but this may help others. Try this plugin - http://wordpress.org/plugins/dynamic-featured-image. It will allow you to add multiple featured image using a graphical interface. It will save lot of your development time.

Answer (score 2):

[Multiple Post Thumbnail](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/multiple-post-thumbnails/)  This Plugin Works Fine With your Requirements but You Should Follow the rules .Click Here   [Useful Link for you](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9899/multiple-post-thumbnails-plugin-and-attachment-error)

Comment: multiple post thumbnail works great.